# Rails: 'No route matches' error even though there is a route match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to open the page `/page` in my *Rails* app, but I get the following error on the *log file*:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/page"):
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/request_store-1.0.6/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/airbrake-4.3.4/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/airbrake-4.3.4/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  .bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.5/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.5/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.5/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.5/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.5/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

I looked up in `bundle exec rake routes`, and it seems like **there is a route matches `[GET] "/page"`**:

```
root GET      /page(.:format)                                                   page#index
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: please share contents of routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my **subdomain** was wrong. It worked with the right subdomain :)